# How to insert a script in Gmail Status?

Tags: javascript

Basically I want to insert a countdown script into my Gmail custom status which would look something like - "5 Days to go.. ". Any help on how to insert the script would be really appreciated. Also, I found a JavaScript  for countdown over [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/count2.shtml). Please guide me over if this is the correct script.

Comment: to clarify, you are trying to write a script that will auto-update your gmail status with the current value of the countdown?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below lines of code,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://formscentral.acrobat.com/Clients/Current/FormsCentral/htmlClient/scripts/adobe.form.embed.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var fggEmZbx4bipRZOYKMGXyAQ = new ADOBEFORMS.EmbedForm({formId:"ggEmZbx4bipRZOYKMGXyAQ", server:"https://adobeformscentral.com/", width:1080, showHeader:false, transparent:true, widthAfterRedirect:1080, heightAfterRedirect:400});
fggEmZbx4bipRZOYKMGXyAQ.display();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you could do it as it would be a serious security threat to have any kind of code execution in an email (think about it, would you like to receive an email with a script in it?).

I would advise just making it your daily routine to switch your signature.

Comment: i dont want it in email.. i am talking about status message.. its the text that you see along-with your status (Available/Busy .. etc)

Comment: Find an XMPP client that logs in as you and just changes your status as necessary.

Comment: I think he wants to automate the process.

Comment: @Matt - yup, i want to automate the process.. i remember i was able to do that for ancient Orkut status messages. But I dont remember what exactly I used to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) is what you're looking for :). Or, if you want to get exotic about it [Chickenfoot](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/chickenfoot/examples.html). Regarding Brad's reservation about security this is, I believe, not a concern since you're essentially updating user-side data that Google's ajax code will then sync with server - whether you or Greasemonkey updates the user-side data is of no importance (except to you).